# Why does this work in IDE but not in CMD Prompt?

Tags: python, cmd, callback

The code reaches out to a message board and indexes/reports the top topics. Using WING IDE, it works fine and reports no errors. However, when ran via command prompt, it will error out saying it can't properly encode a character. This is the first time I've seen this and haven't found a good resource to fix it.

Being that it runs fine in WING, I'm unsure what else to add to the code that would prevent this issue from happening in the command prompt.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = raw_input("Enter the board URL: ")

print "\n"

#send the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:

    #pull the content
    html_content = response.content

    #send the page to BeautifulSoup
    html_doc = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

    #extract topic data
    topic_spider = html_doc.find_all("span",{"class":"subject"})
    data = []
    for topic in topic_spider:
        if topic.text!='':
            data.append(topic.text)
    topiclist = list(dict.fromkeys(data))
    topiclist.sort(reverse=False)
    for item in topiclist:
        print ('[*] ' + item)
```

WING runs this just fine with no errors. Via CMD, the following result occurs after several successful results:

```
[*] Parenting (successful result)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\xxxx\topicindexer.py", line 29, in <module>
    print ('[*] ' + item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 31: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: I understand what it's saying. What I don't understand is the proper way to correct it.

Comment: Don't use smart quotes. CMD is OEM code page by default. Program to your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note two things.

One, you use print statements like this

```
print ('[*] ' + item)
```

which indicates you're using python 3.x

Second, however, your cmd output uses python 2.7. 
That appears to be your problem. Try `python3 filename.py` on the commandline instead of `python filename.py`, as that is what it defaults to when you have both installed.

See if this solves it before anything else.

Comment: I took that idea from another post, so bad on me for using the wrong syntax here.

I installed an updated 3.x Python, but it still doesn't like the python3 command:
***
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
***

Unable to uninstall python3 now, so now it's made it break regardless because it's expecting 3,0 throughout.

hmmmm

Comment: Having multiple versions of python installed can get messy, personally I'd suggest just uninstalling 2.7 unless you desperately need it. Then totally reinstalling the latest 3.x, make sure to check the box that adds things to the PATH variable in the installer and all that. That way python3 should then just function under the `python` command instead of python3.

Comment: I'll follow up on that asap.

I'm going through a course that uses 2.7, so hence the outdated syntax. I realize it's behind; I was just trying to stay with the course material.

I'll try to re-write it and see how it goes.

Comment: Sounds good, I've got to go so best of luck to you, there aren't too many critical differences between the two in terms of syntax for most stuff, just remember to bracket your prints and you'll be 99% fine. BeautifulSoup4 docs note the module functions basically the same for 2.7 and 3.x so you should be fine using that

Comment: Uninstalled the un-used version...

So here's the weird thing. If i hop over into my admin account on this machine, it runs fine... But going back into my usual user account, it breaks the same way (even when running CMD as admin). That's a new one for me, but I'm going to chalk it up to something being weird in the environment.

Comment: Sounds like something was only installed under the admin user and not under yours, I think pip defaults to only installing in certain places for example (e.g. per-user if it wasn't ran as admin) depending on how you run it. Annoying part of Python. I think you're probably right on the environment part though I'm not remotely knowledgeable to enough to tell you how to fix it from here without totally obliterating it all from every user account and reinstalling :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the python environment in CMD and Wing is the same. 
Set the environment variables that's in Wing IDE in CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is written in python 3 but your default is set to python 2.

When running your code in CMD just add `python3 myfile.py` rather than just `python myfile.py`